# how to change a string based on index in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column in my data frame which similar to:

```
type
  
phone
smartphone
handphone
handphone
```

and I want to change the first "handphone" to phone, and the second "handphone" to smartphone.
How can I make it in python? So far, what I have done was using df.replace(regex) but it changes both "handphone" as phone, while what I expect is:

```
type

phone
smartphone
phone
smartphone
```

thankyou.

Comment: Where is the attempted approach?

Comment: How do you choose which one to change to phone and which one to change to smartphone?

Comment: What if there are more than two occurrence ?

Comment: @Onyambu I have set the column, so the first handphone will always be phone and the second phone is smartphone

Comment: @sushanth I have minimalized the column so there will be only two occurrence

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## TL;DR

```py
df[df['type'] == 'handphone'] = [['phone'], ['smartphone']]
```

## Why does this work?

We are slicing the dataframe to only return cells where they are equal to 'handphone' in the column 'type'. Then, we reassign those cells to be 'phone' and 'smartphone', in order.

### Breaking it down

The first part of the solution:

```py
df[df['type'] == 'handphone']
```

Prints:

```py
[['handphone'], ['handphone']]
```

And then when we reassign it with:

```py
df[df['type'] == 'handphone'] = [['phone'], ['smartphone']]
```

So it becomes this:

```py
[['phone'], ['smartphone']]
```

Comment: or, ``df.loc[df.type.eq('handphone'), 'type'] = ['phone', 'smartphone']``

Comment: @sushanth Yeah, although this actually might take longer to run because of the added search for type.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can make this a list, here is a simple solution that should work:

```
lists = ["phone", "smartphone", "handphone", "handphone"]
changelist = ["phone", "smartphone"]

num = 0
for row in range(len(lists)):
    if lists[row] == "handphone":
        lists[row] = changelist[num]
        num += 1

print(lists)

>>>['phone', 'smartphone', 'phone', 'smartphone']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.Series(['phone', 'smartphone', 'handphone', 'handphone'])
df[df[df == 'handphone'].index[0]] = 'phone' # Find the first occurrence of 'handphone' and replace it with 'phone'
df[df[df == 'handphone'].index[0]] = 'smatphone' # Find the first occurrence of 'handphone' again, but now it will be the equivalent of the second occurrence, and replace it with 'smartphone'

print(df)
```

Output:

```
0         phone
1    smartphone
2         phone
3     smatphone
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("File.csv") # File.csv have your given data in question

my_type = df["type"].tolist() # Series to list

index_phone = my_type.index("handphone")
my_type[index_phone] = "phone"

index_phone = my_type.index("handphone")
my_type[index_phone] = "smartphone"

my_type
```

Output:

```
['phone', 'smartphone', 'phone', 'smartphone']
```